# Choose PySpark version in IPython session

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

We have two available versions of Spark (1.6 and 2.1).  I've set environment variables (such as `SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2`) such that, when opening pyspark or spark-shell directly, it uses Spark 2.1.  However, when I try to import pyspark in an IPython session, it uses Spark 1.6.  How do I set it to use 2.1 by default?

Comment: Have you tried setting the spark_home and path as below                           export SPARK_HOME=<spark 2.1 folder> 
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by setting the following environment variables:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

and adding the following to my IPython startup:

```
import sys
import os

os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/"
sys.path.append("/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/python")
sys.path.append("/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/python/build")
```